# Setting android-for-work profile on Samsung Galaxy Tab

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, samsung-galaxy-note, profiles

I have being trying to set a android-for-work profile on my Samsung Galaxy Note Pro but the only thing that I managed to do is to define a new normal google profile. I have successfully set my android-for-work profile on my Nexus 6.
The Samsung Galaxy Note Pro runs Lollipop

Does someone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I am actually running Android Lollipop

Comment: Install [Android for Work](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.work.core) app from Google Play as your device is not supported to have a work-profile

Comment: I did it but I cannot open It.

Comment: I get "This content is not available in your country yet." when I click on that link. I am in the UK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a work profile is only available on supported devices (see the link in the first answer).

The "android for work app" is only needed on devices running android < 5. Installing it on a unsupported device does nothing.

-> As far as i investigated, you cannot use work profiles on unsupported devices.

---

My question is, what happens if the admin enforces usage of a work profile? Can users with unsupported devices still use their apps-account (I think not...).

Comment: I have enforced the need for a work profile. It does nothing on unsupported devices.

Answer (score 1):

The Android for Work app only works with 3rd party EMM solutions. It doesn't work with Google's own EMM which is kind of stupid.
As far as I can tell, if you device isn't on the list of supported devices you cannot manage application installs with Google Apps EMM. You can only do things like enforce password policies etc.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you set-up with Nexus 6 successfully but cannot set-up with Samsung Galaxy Note pro is because [Nexus 6 and only a handful of other devices](https://www.google.co.in/work/android/features/devices.html) support Work profile on Android.

---

For devices that don't support a work profile natively, you need to install [Android for Work App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.work.core) 

<sub>Before installing this App, uninstall [Divide App from Enterproid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.enterproid.divideinstaller) if you have it installed as it interferes with Google for Work</sub>

- Once the App is installed, Configure your Work domain.
- Enter your username and password for your work domain.
- [Optional] Enter a PIN or Password for your Work screen lock if requested.

<sup>After setting-up you can install you can [install the Divide](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6173530) Productivity App</sup>

Comment: I installed the android for work app. However I could not open it. It just say that it is installed. Do you know the reason of it?